# Read, process and write a file in chunks

Tags: python-3.6

I have two programs that do exactly what I want.  I am trying to combine them into a single program, and this is where I need some assistance.

Program #1 reads an entire file, readlines(), processes it, and then writes the data to a new file.  Works perfectly.

Code:

```
datafile = "d:\\python\\workbook\\countries-raw.txt"

with open(datafile, "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()

content = [i.strip('\n') for i in content if '\n' in i]
content = [i for i in content if i != ""]
content = [i for i in content if i != "Top of Page"]
content = [i for i in content if len(i) != 1]

print(content)

newfile = "d:\\python\\workbook\\countries-raw-2.txt"

with open(newfile, "w") as file2:
    for i in content:
        file2.write(i + '\n')
```

Program #2 reads a file in chunks, X lines at a time. It then prints the data
X lines at a time.  It also works exactly as intended.

Code with sample output:

```
textfile = "d:\\mark\\python\\test.txt"


def read_n(file, x):
    with open(file, mode='r') as fh:
        while True:
            data = ''.join(fh.readline() for _ in range(x))

            if not data:
                break

            yield data


for nlines in read_n(textfile, 5):
    print(nlines)

'''    
    abc
    123
    def
    456
    ghi

    789
    jkl
    abc
    123
    def

    456
    ghi
    789
    jkl
    abc

    123
    def
    456
    ghi
    789

    jkl
    abc
    123
    def
    456

    ghi
    789
    jkl
'''
```

What I am wanting is to combine their functionality.  Suppose I have to process a file with 20+ million (or more) lines of text.  I may not be able
to read in the entire file and create a huge list like in Program #1.

However, this seems like it would be unnecessarily slow:

Read in one line.
Process the line.
Write the line.
Repeat until the whole file is processed.

I was thinking my second program's logic would be great here:

Read in X lines.
Process all of the X lines.
Write the lines (may not be exactly X depending upon what I am doing).
Repeat until the whole file is processed.

This is what I have but it does not work: (NOTE the contents in the list [content] are correct after the final comprehension is processed.)

```
textfile = "d:\\python\\workbook\\countries-raw.txt"
newfile = "d:\\python\\workbook\\temp-2.txt"

def read_n(file, x):
    with open(file, mode='r') as fh:
        while True:
            data = ''.join(fh.readline() for _ in range(x))
            content = data.split('\n')
            content = [i for i in content if i != ""]
            content = [i for i in content if i != "Top of Page"]
            content = [i for i in content if len(i) != 1]

            if not content:
                break

            yield content


for nlines in read_n(textfile, 50):
    with open(newfile, "w") as file2:
        for item in content:
            content.write(item + '\n')
    print(nlines)
```

At a minimum I have a scoping issue because PyCharm says 'content' is unknown in the lower printing section.  Also, if possible, when the file is written I do not want spaces between the data as appears in the output of program #2.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out:

```
for nlines in read_n(textfile, 50):
    with open(newfile, "a") as file2:
        for item in nlines:
            file2.write(item + '\n')
    print(nlines)
```